# Google Sheet Query - Query different ranges on same sheet depending on value in a cell

Tags: conditional-statements, range

I have multiple tables of data on a single sheet that I want to be able to pull data from depending on a value in a cell.

How can I use the query function to query different ranges in the same sheet depending on a value in a cell? For example:

```
       If A1 = "Cost", Query A2:G5 and including values from Column A, B,D  
        If A1 = "Tax", Query Range A10:G15, including values from Column A, B, D
          If A1 = "Revenue", Query Range A20:G30, including values from Column A, B, D
```

Really nothing. Have not started yet.